# Connection timed out while connecting to AWS DocumentDB outside the VPC

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-documentdb

I'm trying create a very simple node app that can use DocumentDB. I'm not using Cloud9 neither Lambda, I'm coding locally. I was following this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html and this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-ec2.html

I created a poorly secured EC2 instance with the following inbound rules

| port range | protocol | source | security group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | TCP | 0.0.0.0/0 | demoEC2 |

This `demoEC2` security group has the following inbound rules

| type | protocol | port range | source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SSH | TCP | 22 | 0.0.0.0/0 |

Then I created a DocumentDB cluster with 1 instance available that belongs to a security group that has the following inbound rules

| type | protocol | port range | source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| custom tcp | TCP | 27017 | demoEC2 |

After that, I open my terminal and created a tunnel:

```sh
ssh -i "mykeypair.pem" -L 27017:<CLUSTER ENDPOINT>:27017 ec2-user@<EC2 PUBLIC IPV4 DNS> -N
```

And, to test if my tunnel is working, I connect using mongoshell:

```
> mongo "mongodb://<MASTER USERNAME>:<MASTER PASSWORD>@localhost:27017/<DATABASE>" --tls --tlsAllowInvalidHostnames --tlsCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
MongoDB shell version v4.2.13
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/<DATABASE>?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2021-07-29T10:10:59.309+0200 W  NETWORK  [js] The server certificate does not match the host name. Hostname: localhost does not match docdb-2021-07-27-10-32-49.ctuxybn342pe.eu-central-1.docdb.amazonaws.com docdb-2021-07-27-10-32-49.cluster-ctuxybn342pe.eu-central-1.docdb.amazonaws.com docdb-2021-07-27-10-32-49.cluster-ro-ctuxybn342pe.eu-central-1.docdb.amazonaws.com , Subject Name: C=US,ST=Washington,L=Seattle,O=Amazon.com,OU=RDS,CN=docdb-2021-07-27-10-32-49.ctuxybn342pe.eu-central-1.docdb.amazonaws.com
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("63340995-54ad-471b-aa8d-85763f3c7281") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.0
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match

Warning: Non-Genuine MongoDB Detected

This server or service appears to be an emulation of MongoDB rather than an official MongoDB product.

Some documented MongoDB features may work differently, be entirely missing or incomplete, or have unexpected performance characteristics.

To learn more please visit: https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/non-genuine-mongodb-server-warning.

rs0:PRIMARY>
```

However, when I try to connect in my node app:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const username = ...
const password = ...
const database = ...

const connstring = `mongodb://${username}:${password}@localhost:27017/${database}?tls=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred`;
const certFile = path.resolve(__dirname, './rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem');
const certFileBuf = fs.readFileSync(certFile); //I tried this one in tlsCAFile option as well

mongoose.connect(connstring,
    {
        tlsCAFile: certFile,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        tlsAllowInvalidHostnames: true,
    }
).then(() => console.log('Connection to DB successful'))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err, 'Error'));
```

I get a connection timeout error after a while:

```
> > node .\index.js
(node:12388) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [<CLUSTER ENDPOINT WITHOUT HAVING .cluster->:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection timed out
    at connectionFailureError (D:\projects\documentdb-connect\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:345:14)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (D:\projects\documentdb-connect\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:313:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:481:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (D:\projects\documentdb-connect\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:441:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at D:\projects\documentdb-connect\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:564:14
    at D:\projects\documentdb-connect\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:1013:9
    at D:\projects\documentdb-connect\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:32:7
    at callback (D:\projects\documentdb-connect\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:283:5)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (D:\projects\documentdb-connect\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:313:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:481:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) Error
```

Since I could connect using mongoshell, I think the tunnel is working and I can even do some inserts on it, but why Mongoose can't connect? I tried also using the MongoClient (`const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient` and `MongoClient.connect(same everything)`) but it didn't worked, I'm still getting the same timeout error.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all I need to do is to pass the username and password through the options, not in the connection string:

```js
const connstring = `mongodb://localhost:27017/${database}`;
const certFile = path.resolve(__dirname, './rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem');
const certFileBuf = fs.readFileSync(certFile);

mongoose.connect(connstring,
    {
        tls: true,
        tlsCAFile: certFile,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        tlsAllowInvalidHostnames: true,
        auth: {
            username,
            password
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: i am now at the place where could connect with mongosh but not nodejs, i tried your suggestion but it didnt make any difference, any more suggestions

Comment: Not really, that was the only thing that I needed to do... :(. Maybe that was a problem specific to nodejs at that time on not accepting auth in the connection string.